# M2E Plugin options not visible even after installing the plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I am facing the strangest of the issues with M2E Plug in and Eclipse 3.6(Helios). I am using Maven 2.2.1

I installed the plugin through both the available site option and the marketplace client and the plugin installation is happening fine. However the Maven options just seems to disappear from the editor intermittently.I say this because when I right click on a project I should get the Maven options but I am not able to see any. I also checked in Window->Preferences and couldnt find the Maven option. The worst part is this is intermittent and I cant seem to figure out what is wrong.

Changing the IDE version is not an option as it is mandatory to develop in client supplied softwares.

Got the M2E plugin from M2E - http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Comment: Just to make sure, are your project under control of m2e? For example, you create the project by Importing Existing Maven Project, and etc.  A normal Spring project, as I remember, doesn't show those M2E options

Comment: The Plugin was working for me when I installed it first. So I imported an existing Maven Project into my workspace and then all the Maven options just disappeared from view.

Comment: The M2E options just came back now. I am sure its going to disappear after some time. This is a freak show.

Comment: Make sure the two M2 and JAVA_HOME env vars are setup correctly. I had a similar case in which I was 100% sure that I set `%JAVA_HOME%` until I discovered a typo...

Answer (score 0):

I am not facing this issue anymore. The only thing that I did is to reinstall the m2e plugin several times from the market it seems to eventually have been fixed.

Regards,
Arun